# Unity Game suddenly has poor performance on Samsung S8, but still perfect in editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

The last few days I have been building a simple platformer to be deployed on Android Phones. However, after the last deploy to my phone, the framerate was bearly at 25fps on my quite fast Samsung S8. The game in the editor is somewhere at 100 fps and works fine. The game also worked fine on my S8 just a day before. I have not really changed anything, so what could be going on here? This is absolutely unacceptable. If you need further info, tell me!

Thank you!

This is from the profiler: [image]

Comment: You have to use [profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/Profiler.html) to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: hi Ali, I set up the profiler. What am I to read from it?

Comment: Check out what is blocking your main thread. You can click on it which will pause the game and then you can see every operation (Rendering, Scripts, Physics etc)at that particular frame and see which operation takes how many ms. Also it would be nice if you share screenshot of it here.

Comment: I posted a screenshot. I hope it is really showing my phone and not anything else... (because even when the game is off in unity, the profiler is still doing something...)

Comment: Sorry, NOW this is the correct screenshot from my phone !

Comment: @AliKanat please tell me you can read anything from it... xD

Comment: Well it shows quite okay fps rates but i have to ask what does that `PlayerLoop` script does? I am suspecting it has something to do with the problem :)

Comment: @AliKanat it looks okay to me too. mostly around 60 fps. however, i can tell with my naked eye that the phone doesnt put out more than 20-25 frames max. this is really confusing... However, the "PlayerLoop" is not my script. I dont know what it does... :(

Comment: @AliKanat see my own answer, i solved it... dont know how, but I did...

Comment: Excuse my ignorance apparently [playerloop](https://vncastanheira.github.io/2018/11/22/playerloop/) is related to Unity itself. I am glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try deducing number of Tries and Vertices in your Meshes, Use baked lighting to improve performance, Also try object pooling wherever possible, and generate Occlusion map to optimize your game for mobile devices. You can set quality settings from Unity for mobile devices. You will need to maintain LOD levels if you want more complex meshes to be rendered on your phone, and optimize game as much as possible to render it on mobile devices without any glitches. I will also recommend you to use this [toolset](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization), which will help you in optimization.

**UPDATE**
If you have recently changed anything, which made your app performance Bad, then check you haven't added any Co-routine or IEnumetaror relative code that may iterate over time in separate thread in your recent changes, try using [Collab](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/collaborate) to maintain versioning, as you can restore your previous code with help of collab anytime, in case you loose something, it is totally free and very useful.

Comment: Hello. Altough I thank you for your great reply, I literally didnt understand a single thing. Are you talking about altering the "Graphics" portion under Project Settings? Everything here is set to default and I have never changed it. Again, evertyhing worked yesterday, all I did was change a few lines of code (which I also changed back already.) Anyway, where do I find what you have been talking about? Or where can I read more about it? Thank you!

Comment: Check here for quality Settings https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html

Comment: And also check you haven't added any Coroutine or IEnumetaror relative code that may iterate over time in seperate thread in your recent changes, try using Collab to maintain versioning, as you can restore your previous code with help of collab anytime, if you loose something.

Comment: I havent added anything that piles up. The performance is super low from the get go. All Quality settings are on low. I have never touched those anyway at all... It must be a script then...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you, why this happend but this was all I needed to do:

In any script that starts (like playermovement or what ever) add this line:

```
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
```

E voila.

I didnt have this line before and it worked but it stopped working. Adding this line fixed it entierely. Thank you all.